# Printing ERD from SchemaSpy output

Tags: database, database-design, schemaspy

We have quite a large database schema and our business analysts would print it and take it to meetings.  Is there any way to get schema spy to print an ERD to 1 A3 page?

Comment: how did the business analysts do it?

Comment: They used Visio, we are trying to automate the process

Answer (score 2):

SourceForge messed with the Wiki that was being used for the [SchemaSpy FAQ which mentions printing ERDs](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/schemaspy/).  I've replaced the page but still need to update the links to it.

You should be able to specify the dimensions for an A3 page directly using the approach listed there.

Comment: Link didn't work for me but found the FAQ via google and got the answer. Thanks.